# No X-Endpoint-API-UserInfo header forwarded by Extensible Service Proxy

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

I'm setting up a pet project using Google Cloud Endpoints and Google Cloud Functions, with Google ID token authentication. I've followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-google-id) guides to set things up, however the `X-Endpoint-API-UserInfo` header is not passed to the cloud function.

I've have one POST endpoint set up in [this](https://github.com/esgott/full-pocket/blob/master/api-generator/openapi.yaml) OpenAPI yaml. It's deployed to Cloud Endpoints, and also an Extensible Service Proxy. When I call this from Postman with a token generated with `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`, I find that the authentication does work, but only the following headers are present in the function: `host, user-agent, transfer-encoding, accept, accept-encoding, authorization, cache-control, forwarded, function-execution-id, postman-token, x-appengine-city, x-appengine-citylatlong, x-appengine-country, x-appengine-default-version-hostname, x-appengine-https, x-appengine-region, x-appengine-request-log-id, x-appengine-user-ip, x-cloud-trace-context, x-forwarded-for, x-forwarded-proto, x-real-ip, connection`

Can you help me why I don't get the user info from ESP in the function?

Comment: hey @esgott, I have tried Wayne Zhang solution and it worked for me. Can you confirm if it works for you and this is what you really want to do?

Comment: Interesting, I've just tried it again, and I can't go through authentication any more. I get `401 Unauthorized` with message `JWT validation failed: Bad JWT format: Invalid JSON in header`. I'm wondering if my way of generating access token is good.

Comment: With the error you get make sure your JWT contains valid JSON. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-jwt) you can find an example of a decoded JWT token that is valid.

Answer (score 2):

I just verified that ESP does send X-Endpoint-Api-Userinfo header to the backend Function.

Here is my backend code

```
cat hello.go 
// Package helloworld provides a set of Cloud Functions samples.
package helloworld

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "html"
        "net/http"
)

// HelloHTTP is an HTTP Cloud Function with a request parameter.
func HelloHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        for key, vals := range r.Header {
                for _, val := range vals {
                        resp := fmt.Sprintf("request-headers: %s=%s\n", key, val)
                        w.Write([]byte(resp))
                }
        }
        var d struct {
                Name string `json:"name"`
        }
        if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&d); err != nil {
                fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World!")
                return
        }
        if d.Name == "" {
                fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello, World!")
                return
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %s!\n", html.EscapeString(d.Name))
}
```

Here is the headers from the backend

```
request-headers: X-Appengine-Country=ZZ
request-headers: X-Appengine-Default-Version-Hostname=gef3fd9f75048d933-tp.appspot.com
request-headers: X-Appengine-Request-Log-Id=5db8910800ff043c9b1b0b1d300001737e67656633666439663735303438643933332d7470000161313837383661623961353931326664363534373361386233343137366433633a33000100
request-headers: X-Endpoint-Api-Userinfo=deducted
request-headers: X-Forwarded-Proto=https
request-headers: X-Real-Ip=100.117.29.55
request-headers: Connection=close
request-headers: User-Agent=curl/7.64.0
request-headers: Accept=*/*
request-headers: Authorization=Bearer deducted
request-headers: Forwarded=for="100.117.29.55";proto=https,for="107.178.206.195";proto=https
request-headers: X-Appengine-Https=on
request-headers: X-Appengine-User-Ip=107.178.206.195
request-headers: X-Endpoint-Api-Project-Id=402804073044
request-headers: X-Forwarded-For=100.117.29.55, 100.117.29.55,107.178.206.195
request-headers: Accept-Encoding=gzip
request-headers: Function-Execution-Id=fea3ox4erxsd
request-headers: X-Cloud-Trace-Context=db9bb39b72286dd6282f5319a18f72c8/9278156698602755161;o=1
```